# How does BLE scanning work for altbeacon library on Oreo?

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, altbeacon, android-8.0-oreo

Before Android L Android Altbeacon library used background running services to scan BLE beacons. Default scan times are 1.1 seconds in a loop in the foreground and 10 seconds every 5 mins in the background. Also for background tasks alarm manager is used to wakeup the app.

I was looking at how similar setup works in Android Oreo given that long-running background services are not allowed. I was going through 
http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2017/08/07/beacon-detection-with-android-8
and it did clear something but I am still not completely clear on how scan works with the combination of bluetooth scanning API and job scheduler.

So how is low power scan is used in combination of job scheduler based periodic scheduling to monitor and range beacons? If someone could provide an example that would be great.

To be a bit more specific -

1. when would we go for passive new beacon detection vrs normal background scans?
2. Why is passive scan work only for new detections? Why can't we run this in a loop? And why is it run only between job scheduler scans?
3. Lets us say I have set scan period of 10 seconds and scan interval of 2 minutes. What techniques are used at what intervals to scan the beacons?
4. If job scheduler can schedule jobs with frequency more than 15 mins and it can run with max 10 mins time can we set scan interval to 10 mins and scan interval to 5 mins? That we would lose only 5 mins worth of scan due to OS limitation? Also, can we do a passive scan in these 5 mins? So we do not have any span of time when beacons are not scanned?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is critical to understand how low power scans work at a low level:

A low power scan relies on offloading the Bluetooth LE pattern matching to a hardware filter on the Bluetooth chip.  If it is matched by an incoming packet, the chip notifies the operating system, which sends an intent to the app that wakes it up to process the packet.

The above relies on a combination on of filtered scans delivered by intents (a new API in Android 8).

When a scheduled scan job ends with the Android Beacon Library, this intent based delivery is set up to be handled by the operating system and Bluetooth chip.  The end result is that if a new beacon is detected, it will be handled by a broadcasted receiver very quickly.  This can send a monitoring callback to the app within a few seconds instead of waiting 15 minutes for the next scheduled job.

This is all designed to work when the filter will not match a Bluetooth device that is already nearby.  If one is already nearby, the Intent would be sent within 100ms or so, which is a very CPU inefficient way of getting constant updates, which defeats the whole point of low power APIs, and would cause the app to be running constantly and eligible for termination by Android 8.

The filter used matches any beacon.  This is done to conserve filters as they are a limited hardware resource.  For this reason, these scanning APIs are not used if a beacon is known to be present already, because it would immediately match a packet and defeat the purpose of the technique.  Bottom line: if a scan job ends with a beacon visible, the low power scanning is not done.

You cannot set a scheduled job to execute any more often than 15 minutes.  This is an operating system restriction.  A 10 minute between scan period would work, but the library only delivers scan results at the end of the cycle, so this probably isn't lot helpful.  It would be possible to modify the library to simply scan for the max 10 minutes on each scan job, but currently it does not do this, and as you note it would leave 5 minutes uncovered.

If you really want to do constant BLE scanning in the background on Android 8+, the OS-permitted way to do so is with a foreground service that displays an icon so the user knows it is running.  Be careful about doing this in consumer apps, though, as battery drain will be very significant and users will probably uninstall the app after blaming it for dead batteries.  For special use cases, however, this may be acceptable.

Comment: So to summarize we start a scheduled job scan first. If beacon is detected in it we do not go for low power scan. But if beacons are not discovered in the schedule job scan we start low power scan to run between the intervals of schedule job scans hoping to get the new beacon (if it becomes visible) thereby not having to wait for another interval time.  

And if by any means one beacons is identified (schedule job scan or low power scan) we never use low power scan again since that would return immediately and waste CPS resource.Correct?

Comment: And @davidgyoung how would altbeacon library detect background mode? As per logic in https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/9902ef7bd822598e6b0b88d4bb38ed066ca5b28a/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/powersave/BackgroundPowerSaver.java it checks for active activities count which I think would be 0 for foreground service?

Comment: The summary is correct, and yes, counting activities is used to determine foreground/background.  For a foreground service to do constant scanning, you would want to set the background scan periods to be constant, and disable the use of scan jobs so the scanning service does so constantly.  See the experimental PR here:  https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/pull/663

Comment: thanks. And if I set a scan interval of 5 minutes what would happen given anything more frequent than 15 mins will not be respected by OS. Will library handle this by using 15 mins interval or something may go bad?

Comment: And @davidgyoung if we do not instantiate BackgroundPowerSaver I think it would always run with foreground time intervals> So we either instantiate it or set it ourselves in BeaconManager.

Comment: If you do not instantiate BackgroundPowerSaver it will always use foregroundScanPeriod an foregroundBetweenScanPeriod.  Whichever scan periods are active, if running Android 8+ and the Android OS determines the app is in the background (basically no visible activities) then scheduled scanning jobs will happen every scanPeriod+betweenScanPeriod (or every ~15 minutes), whichever is greater.